# 404 Error on urllib2.urlopen()

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to scrape a website using urllib2. However I get a 400 Page not found error. Here is my code:

```
rec_text = 'Genesis 1:1'
my_text = rec_text.strip()
book = my_text.split()[0]
chapter_verse = my_text.split()[1]
chapter = chapter_verse.split(':')[0]
verse = chapter_verse.split(':')[1]
webpage = urllib2.urlopen('http://bible.cc/'+book+'/'+chapter+'-'+verse+'.htm').read()
stuffToSearch = ""
for line in webpage:
    stuffToSearch += line
search_for = re.compile(r'<a href="http://kingjbible.com/'+book+'/'+chapter+'.htm">King James Bible</a></span><br>(.*)<p><span class="versiontext"><a href="http://kjv.us/'+book+'/'+chapter+'.htm">')
search_it = re.search(search_for, stuffToSearch)
print(search_it.group(1))
```

Comment: Make sure the URI you're trying to `urlopen` points to an available resource.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the `bible.cc` site, it appears that capitalization matters. You need `genesis` and not `Genesis`, which you can get by changing the line to `book = my_text.split()[0].lower()`.

**Edit**: The rest of this doesn't actually relate to the error, but has some other tips.

You can streamline your code a bit by using multiple assignment where you have two or more values being output from one operation.

```
rec_text = 'Genesis 1:1'
my_text = rec_text.strip().lower()
book, chapter_verse = my_text.split()
chapter, verse = chapter_verse.split(':')
```

There's also a way to join a list of strings together without having to use a for loop. Use `join` where the string calling it will be used as the separator between the elements of the list (basically the opposite of `split`).

```
stuffToSearch = "".join(webpage)
```

I guess there's nothing wrong with the page retrieval, though I'd imagine `readlines` would be slightly more efficient than `read`. Same with the regular expression; you don't need to compile it if you're only using it once. You could probably easily come up with an expression that's independent of the book and chapter that can be used repeatedly, however.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer; I figured it was the 'Genesis' instead of 'genesis' affair. And thanks for the extra information, very useful!

Answer (score 0):

The process is right, just that the url formed might not be correct.

Why don't you assign `'http://bible.cc/'+book+'/'+chapter+'-'+verse+'.htm'` this to some variable & print it before sending it to `urlopen`?

This way you can verify if the url is formed correct.

Comment: I figured it out. The url in question takes 'book', while I had passed 'Book', hence the 404. Thanks!